# Activity stuck in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: activities-overview

After updating to Ubuntu 21.04 today and even disabling all gnome extensions, I have a problem where it will not close/exit if I open Activities. I've tried using Super again to toggle, escape, or run a new program (which usually closes it). Nothing seems to work to fix it from being keyboard useless then. It happens every time it opens. This issue is critical as once Activities is stuck open, the user cannot interact with any windows, and they must log out

P.S this problem is no more in Ubuntu 22.04 until now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting locked into 'Activities/Overview' after Super Key on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335361/why-am-i-getting-locked-into-activities-overview-after-super-key-on-ubuntu-21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue for me.
I fixed it by disabling Dash to Panel extension and re-enabled multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have randomly become stuck in the activities overview: try restarting the GNOME shell by pressing alt-f2 and typing "r". See [this discussion](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/gnome-shell-overview-stuck-on/22216).

Comment: you save my currently running processes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem from time to time. I usually switch into a different tty:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. Login and run:

   ```
   killall -3 gnome-shell
   ```
3. Return to the graphic tty: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>